# elements won't keep desired aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I am creating memory game. I want  24 cards (6 cards in 4 rows). Problem is that DIV elements are placed one bellow each other. I tried to delete few things from my CSS but for some reason problem is still there. Can someone tell me why my html looks like this and share advice how to fix it. Regards.

This is what i want to achive:

[image: This picture show what I want to have]

And this is what I have

[image: This is what I have]

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="picbox">
   <span id="boxbuttons">
   <span class="button" id="rezz">
   Rezultat
   <span id="counter">0</span>
   </span>
   <span class="button" id="ttime">00 : 14</span>
   <span class="button">
   <a onclick="ResetGame();">Reset</a>
   </span> 
   <span class="button">
   <a onclick="MutedSound();">Mute sound</a>
   </span> 
   </span>
   <div id="boxcard" align="center">
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper10">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img5.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992640c06707c66a5c0b08a2549c69745dc2c.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper11">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper12">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699263b01721074bf094aa3bc695aa19c8d573.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper13">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img3.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699259cb2d70c6882adc285ab8d519658b5dd7.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper14">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img3.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699259cb2d70c6882adc285ab8d519658b5dd7.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper15">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img4.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992601ca0f28ba4a8f7b41f99ee026d7aaed8.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper16">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992554c2ca340cc2ea8c0606ecd320824756e.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper17">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img2.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925824ea93cbb77ba9e95c1a4cec7f89b80c.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper18">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992568b759acd78f7cbe98b6e4a7baa90e717.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper19">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992568b759acd78f7cbe98b6e4a7baa90e717.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper110">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/sport/96/Volleyball-icon.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper111">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img4.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992601ca0f28ba4a8f7b41f99ee026d7aaed8.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper20">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699263b01721074bf094aa3bc695aa19c8d573.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper21">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992554c2ca340cc2ea8c0606ecd320824756e.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper22">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper23">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img5.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992640c06707c66a5c0b08a2549c69745dc2c.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper24">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/sport/96/Volleyball-icon.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper25">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper26">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925708af4fb3c954b1d856da1f4d4dcd548a.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper27">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper28">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925708af4fb3c954b1d856da1f4d4dcd548a.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper29">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699262833250fa3063b708c41042005fda437d.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper210">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img2.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925824ea93cbb77ba9e95c1a4cec7f89b80c.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper" id="flipper211">
         <div class="front"></div>
         <div class="back"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699262833250fa3063b708c41042005fda437d.png"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font: 18px Verdana;
    color: #FFF;
  background: #CCC;
}
#picbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard {
/*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:1000;
   -moz-perspective:1000;
    -ms-perspective:1000;
     -o-perspective:1000;
        perspective:1000;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}

.flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.front, .back{
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        z-index:2;
  background: #B1B1B1;
   /*   position:absolute;*/

    /*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;

}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
   -moz-transition:0.6s;
     -o-transition:0.6s;
        transition:0.6s;
/*transform-style*/
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
            position:relative;

/*position:relative;*/
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
/* front pane, placed above back */
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back{
/*transform*/

-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
    z-index:3;
}
#boxbuttons {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
}
#boxbuttons .button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EE872A;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#boxbuttons .button:hover {
    background: #999;
}
```

Comment: well using this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pVLa7/ the items are lining up as you want. is this being wrapped in another div and I presume you have some js to hide the items with images on them.

Comment: Where are the `.back` elements in your "what I want to achieve" graphic?

Comment: with JS i am applying "flipped" div that performs transormation @DavidShorthose.

Comment: @showdev .back elemenents hold image that showup after .flipped. is added by JS. .flipped performs rotation and back image is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing at the very least something like:

```
.flipper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(by default, a div is a block element, which means that blocks are one below the other)

Also, when you post a question, please post only the relevant code...

Comment: sorry for inrelevant code. I will try your solution and will post back results.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this on the boxcard:

```
width:100%;
```

and remove all this, again on the boxcard ( you're repeating code-- not good):

```
display: table;
margin: 0px auto;
width: auto;
z-index: 1;
display: table;
margin: 0px auto;
width: auto;
```

add this:

```
#boxcard div{
    float:left;
    margin:5px
}
```

and then you have to fix some of the height problems, which honestly, I don't know where they come from. Maybe from the rotation...

Check it here 
http://jsfiddle.net/4bxjN/

But if you want my opinion, I would use a table in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/B7pjw/

Then you can put whatever you need inside of it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem is that .back div is showing and it's taking too much space. I ll play with your code and post back results. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe you'll get better results with a table. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B7pjw/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is that back div is placed below first div so when user clicks on div, immage is showed below clicked div since back div is placed below first div.